# woocommerce read abandoned cart details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying read abandoned cart details in `woocommerce` from table `wp_options`. The string is below format

```
a:19:{s:4:"cart";s:308:"a:1:{s:32:"d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:10;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:189;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:189;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}";s:15:"applied_coupons";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"coupon_discount_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:27:"coupon_discount_tax_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:21:"removed_cart_contents";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:19:"cart_contents_total";d:189;s:20:"cart_contents_weight";i:2;s:19:"cart_contents_count";i:1;s:5:"total";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";i:189;s:15:"subtotal_ex_tax";i:189;s:9:"tax_total";i:0;s:5:"taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"shipping_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:13:"discount_cart";i:0;s:14:"shipping_total";i:0;s:18:"shipping_tax_total";i:0;s:9:"fee_total";i:0;s:4:"fees";s:6:"a:0:{}";}
```

How can i split this value to read the cart and product details.

Comment: See https://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is serialized. You have to unserialize it. You can use a online tool for it.

http://www.unserialize.com/

Or, you can run a PHP code;

```
<?php

   $serialized = 'a:19:{s:4:"cart";s:308:"a:1:{s:32:"d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:10;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:189;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:189;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}";s:15:"applied_coupons";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"coupon_discount_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:27:"coupon_discount_tax_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:21:"removed_cart_contents";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:19:"cart_contents_total";d:189;s:20:"cart_contents_weight";i:2;s:19:"cart_contents_count";i:1;s:5:"total";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";i:189;s:15:"subtotal_ex_tax";i:189;s:9:"tax_total";i:0;s:5:"taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"shipping_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:13:"discount_cart";i:0;s:14:"shipping_total";i:0;s:18:"shipping_tax_total";i:0;s:9:"fee_total";i:0;s:4:"fees";s:6:"a:0:{}";}';

   $unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );

   var_dump( $unserialized );

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The string you are displaying is serialized. [Serializing](https://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is a way of storing a PHP value (in this case an array), together with its type and structure, as a string.

You can use PHP's [`unserialize`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to transform the string back into a PHP value:

```
$value = unserialize($value);
```

This will return an array that contains a `cart` key, which is for some reason serialized as well, so you will have to use `unserialize` again:

```
$cart = unserialize($value['cart']);
```

Now you will be able to access the cart data.

```
echo $cart['d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820']['product_id']; // 10
```